# To get the radio button values in ruby on rails using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have created a quiz i want the the display the questions in one per pageand my partial view of _ans is given below in that the next link is works when i checked the radio button.. i want the help to get the radio button values if i checked ,if i doesn't checked it returns null

```
 <div id = "main1">
  <% form_for @answer do |f|%>
    <div class = "questions">
      <div id = "passage">
        <%= "Passage"%>:<br>
      <%#= @ans.passage %>
      </div> <br>
      <label>
        <%= @s %> . <%= @ans.ques %>
      </label>  
      <div id = "options">
        <label for "options">
          <div id = "option-1">
            <%= radio_button_tag 'ans', 'ans1'%><%= @ans.ans1 %>
          </div><br>
          <div id = "option-2">
            <%= radio_button_tag 'ans', 'ans2'%><%= @ans.ans2 %>
          </div><br>
          <div id = "option-3">
            <%= radio_button_tag 'ans', 'ans3'%><%= @ans.ans3 %>
          </div><br>
          <div id = "option-4">
            <%= radio_button_tag 'ans', 'ans4'%><%= @ans.ans4  %>
          </div><br>
        </label>
      </div><br>
    </div><br><br>
    <div id = "prev">
      <%= link_to_remote "Previous", 
        :before => "Element.show('loader')",
        :success => "Element.hide('loader')",
        :update => "answers",
        :url=>{:controller=>"answers", :action=>"previous"},
        :with => "'&passed_question=#{@ans.id-1}&'+'&exam_group_id=#{@exam_group.id}&'"
      %> 
    </div>
    <div id = "next">
       <%= link_to_remote "Previous", 
        :before => "Element.show('loader')",
        :success => "Element.hide('loader')",
        :update => "answers",
        :url=>{:controller=>"answers", :action=>"previous"},
        :with => "'answer=$$('[name*=ans]:checked)[0].value+'&passed_question=#{@ans.id-1}&'+'&exam_group_id=#{@exam_group.id}&'"
      %> 
    </div>
    <div id = "sub">
      <%= link_to "Submit", final_exam_group_answers_path(@exam_group)%> 
    </div>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(':radio[value=ans1]').prop('checked')
$(':radio[value=ans2]').prop('checked')
$(':radio[value=ans3]').prop('checked')
$(':radio[value=ans4]').prop('checked')
```

Will return true or false for each radio button.

To return false when no radio is selected, true when anything is selected:

```
!!$(':radio:checked')[0]
```

In case you want to return null:

```
!!$(':radio:checked')[0] == false ? null : true;
```

Comment: if i does not check anything it returns null... how can i get

Comment: that's the only thing you need... let me expand my question to meet your need

Comment: It works but if i does not check link_to_remote is not working thats my main problem

Comment: please rewrite your question then... I don't understand